# Python (django) how to deal with money calculations accurately

Tags: python, django, floating-point, decimal, currency

Lets say I have this model with calculations

```
Class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
    tax = models.DecimalField(...)

    @property
    def tax_amount(self):
        return self.amount * self.tax

    @property
    def net(self):
        return self.amount - self.tax_amount
```

When I want to print out the `net` I am using `"{:.2f}".format(txn.net)`

I am worried that if I have multiple transactions and I want to get the sum of tax_amount, the rounding might be different after the addition.

But if I put the `round(x, 2)` around the `tax_amount` property, it will fail in the `net` property because it's Decimal minus float, eg.

```
Class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
    tax = models.DecimalField(...)

    @property
    def tax_amount(self):
        return round(self.amount * self.tax, 2)

    @property
    def net(self):
        # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'Decimal'
        return self.amount - self.tax_amount
```

Comment: Would using the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) help you at all?

Comment: @blakev do you mean using the getcontext?

Comment: @blakev or `with localcontext() as ctx:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we end up to have is creating a function:

```
def r2(v):
    return Decimal(v).quantize(Decimal('0.00'))
```

then wrap all currency related calulations with this function.